# When to use emissivity in Stefan-Boltzmann Law?

Tags: thermodynamics, radiation

In Stefan-Boltzmann Law:

$$q=σAe(T_1^4−T_2^4)$$

I sometimes see it written with emissivity, $e$ and sometimes without. How do you know whether to include it?

I know $e=1$ for an ideal radiator and this is often assumed. However, for the likes of rough aluminium with really low emissivity (0.07) whether $e$ is included or not greatly affects the result.

Comment: Youve answered the question in your question? You use it whenever you apply the stefan boltzmann law to a material which cant be treated as an ideal black body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with the typical definition of the Stefan-Boltzmann Law.

If you choose to define it as the power emitted by a *black body* at a specific temperature (the usual definition), than you wouldn't want to include the emissivity term.  It would always be 1, so including a variable with a constant factor of 1 in front of the equation is just confusing at best.

I would argue that the equation with emissivity is actually a slight modification to the actual *law*; which allows you to apply it to non-black bodies.  The thing is though, it's such a practical application of the Stefan-Boltzmann Law that the two often get introduced together and intertwined.

I wouldn't worry too much about it.  You seem to already understand how the equation is used in practice, and what the variables mean.  It's basically just arguing over definitions at that point.  Some people may consider the version with emissivity as the "Stefan-Boltzmann Law", and I wouldn't bother fighting them on that.  It's more important to understand what the two "versions" of the law actually mean and why they are different, than worry about which one is technically "the Stefan-Boltzmann Law".

Answer (score 0):

The Stefan-Boltzmann law gives the total energy radiated by an ideal black body. For a real body the integrand must be multiplied by a frequency dependent emissivity factor. Therefore the Stefan-Boltzmann law strictly does not hold for a non-ideal radiator. Only if the emissivity is frequency independent the equation holds as you state it. In other cases it is an approximation.